# Manually initializing a ngController

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get an angular library automatically "injected" into the main module when the file is included.

Is there any way to initialize a ng-controller without actually setting the DOM attribute?

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: Yes use $controllerProvider.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Manually initialize a controller usually use only in unit testing.

Comment: I don't see what the second sentence has to do with the first one. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have some ngDirectives and all of them uses the same ngController, but due to the environment where this is working I cannot add DOM attributes manually to the parent elements. That's why I'm trying to "auto-initialize" the ngController

Comment: @MaheshSapkal I have seen that $controllerProvider allows you to register a new controller but I'm trying to "activate" it, you know what I mean?